# How to prove: if $x = y$, then $f(x) = f(y)$ (for a function $f$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The intuition of this for me is that if two elements in the domain are equal, then their images are equal. But I don't know if this is actually true or not, so I want to know if this is for sure. Where should I start in order to show if this statement is true or not?

Comment: What is your definition of function?

Comment: I don't really know a definition other than if you input an element of the domain into the function, it only returns exactly one element as an image.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the statement you're asking about?

Comment: @nablablah: That suffices here. You are inputting _one_ element of the domain (since $x$ is the same as $y$, they are really one element). Then you get _one_ element of the codomain (= set in which $f$ takes it images). In other words $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ (or should I say $f(x)$ and $f(x)$) cannot be different.

Comment: See $x$ and $y$ as 'labels' of the same 'mathematical object'. The function has this 'mathematical object' as argument. Not the labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x=y$,  then $x$ and $y$ denote the same element of $f$'s domain, whose image is determined.

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(t) = 2t$, $x = 1$ and $y = 1$, then surely $f(x) = f(y)$, since $f(1) = 2$, no matter what is your label for $1$.